# How to get first rows of each condition and sum specific fields in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Working on the aggregation framework and stuck. Below are the data I have:

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "FA_NUM" : 194,
    "Cost" : 198,
    "YEAR" : 2020,
    "last_run_date" : ISODate("2020-03-31T01:42:14.121+05:30")
},
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "FA_NUM" : 188,
    "Cost" : 277,
    "YEAR" : 2020,
    "last_run_date" : ISODate("2020-05-30T04:40:16.299+05:30")
},
{
    "_id" : 3,
    "FA_NUM" : 204,
    "Cost" : 160,
    "YEAR" : 2019,
    "last_run_date" : ISODate("2019-12-26T06:22:45.221+05:30")
},
{
    "_id" : 4,
    "FA_NUM" : 105,
    "Cost" : 860,
    "YEAR" : 2019,
    "last_run_date" : ISODate("2019-02-28T10:50:26.279+05:30")
}
```

I need to sort the data on the basis of the year and last_run_date. I achieved this. Here is my query.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$match : {"YEAR" : {$in : [2020, 2019]}}},
    {$sort : {"YEAR":-1, "last_run_date":-1}}
    ])
```

But my requirement is the first row only of each condition like this.

```
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "FA_NUM" : 188,
    "Cost" : 277,
    "YEAR" : 2020,
    "last_run_date" : ISODate("2020-05-30T04:40:16.299+05:30")
},
{
    "_id" : 3,
    "FA_NUM" : 204,
    "Cost" : 160,
    "YEAR" : 2019,
    "last_run_date" : ISODate("2019-12-26T06:22:45.221+05:30")
}
```

Now finally I want to add "FA_NUM" and "Cost" fields and final output should be like this:

```
{FA_NUM : 392, "Cost":437}
```

How could I achieve this in one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically your goal is to do a sum on the latest `FA_SUM` and `Cost` of every year. To do this, you will need to sort the document by `YEAR` and `last_run_date` first and then apply two `group` stage as follows. Note the last `project` stage is just to remove the `_id` field.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $sort: { "YEAR": 1, "last_run_date": 1 } },
    { $group: {
            "_id": "$YEAR",
            "latest": { $last: "$$ROOT" }

       }},
    { $group: {    
           "_id": null,
           "FA_NUM": { $sum:"$latest.FA_NUM" },
           "Cost": { $sum: "$latest.Cost" } 
        }
      },
    { $project : {
        "_id" : 0 ,
        "FA_NUM" : 1 ,
        "Cost" : 1
    }}
])
```

Result:

```
{
    "FA_NUM" : 392,
    "Cost" : 437
}
```

**More details:**

STEP 1: 
After the first `sort` stage, the document will be sorted like:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : 4,
    "FA_NUM" : 105,
    "Cost" : 860,
    "YEAR" : 2019,
    "last_run_date" : ISODate("2019-02-28T10:50:26.279+05:30")
}
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : 3,
    "FA_NUM" : 204,
    "Cost" : 160,
    "YEAR" : 2019,
    "last_run_date" : ISODate("2019-12-26T06:22:45.221+05:30")
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "FA_NUM" : 194,
    "Cost" : 198,
    "YEAR" : 2020,
    "last_run_date" : ISODate("2020-03-31T01:42:14.121+05:30")
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "FA_NUM" : 188,
    "Cost" : 277,
    "YEAR" : 2020,
    "last_run_date" : ISODate("2020-05-30T04:40:16.299+05:30")
}
```

STEP 2: Then, you do a group by on `YEAR` and the `last` operand is to retrieve the last document in each group (in each year). The `$$ROOT` allows you to get the full details of this last document.

```
{
    "_id" : 2020,
    "latest" : {
        "_id" : 2,
        "FA_NUM" : 188,
        "Cost" : 277,
        "YEAR" : 2020,
        "last_run_date" : ISODate("2020-05-30T04:40:16.299+05:30")
    }
}

{
    "_id" : 2019,
    "latest" : {
        "_id" : 3,
        "FA_NUM" : 204,
        "Cost" : 160,
        "YEAR" : 2019,
        "last_run_date" : ISODate("2019-12-26T06:22:45.221+05:30")
    }
}
```

STEP 3: Lastly, we do a group by again to get the sum of the desired values.

```
{
    "_id" : null,
    "FA_NUM" : 392,
    "Cost" : 437
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to sum a field on all documents then you need to use `$group` to group all the documents.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    /** Using match as first stage to filter docs, helps for better performance */
    {
      $match: { "YEAR": { $in: [ 2020, 2019 ] } }
    },
    /** Sorting on descending order */
    {
      $sort: { "YEAR": -1, "last_run_date": -1 }
    },
    /** group on year & get first document from each set - will be only 2 docs left (with 3 fields in each doc)
     *  {_id :..., FA_NUM:...., Cost :.... } after this stage */
    {
      $group: { _id: "$YEAR", FA_NUM: { $first: "$FA_NUM" }, Cost: { $first: "$Cost" } }
    },
    /** group without any condition & sum a field across all docs */
    {
      $group: { _id: "", FA_NUM: { $sum: "$FA_NUM" }, Cost: { $sum: "$Cost" } }
    },
    /** Optional, remove unnecessary field from output */
    {
      $project: { _id: 0 }
    }
  ])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/G_XFdIbqxow)

**Ref :** [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html)